# How to get the absolute url in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, http-headers

I am currently working on a http server in python. I have subclassed BaseHttpRequestHandler to handler a get/post request. As per documentation, BaseHttpRequestHandler  has an instance variable path, but how do i get the full request url

Example http://www.cnn.com/index.html

```
Class handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        # This gives me /index.html
        print self.path
```

But is there a way I can get full url?

Comment: Can you add the path to your domain name?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the server name (and port, if the server is on a specific port) via `self.server.server_name` and `self.server.server_port`. Then just concatenate them - assuming you have a port, and that the server name doesn't include a trailing '/' (can't check at the moment, myself):

```
full_url = ''.join([name, ':', port, '/', path])
```

If you don't have a port specified:

```
full_url = '/'.join([name, path])
```

In both cases, `path` is self.path, and `name` and `port` are as explained at the top.